# Cannot scroll after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I am facing the situation of making an ajax call that populates a DIV which gets as big as 2 web pages long. But I cannot scroll unless I resize the window.
How do I tell the browser to recalculate the size of the page content so it adds the scroll bar?
Thanks!

Ok, here is the code:
As you can see, I am trying with $("#main-content").css({ height:"100vh" });, but it doesn't work.

```js
function showParticipants(){
 
 if($('#action').val() != 0){
    $.ajax('participants.php', {
    beforeSend: function(){
   modal();
    },
    success: function(data) {
   $('#showParticipantsContainer').html(data);
   modal();
   $("#main-content").css({ height:"100vh" });
    },
    data: { ajax: 'showParticipants', idAction: $('#actions').val(), },
    error: showError
    }); 
 }else{
  $('#showParticipantsContainer').empty();
  $('#resultMessageDiv').empty();
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code for us to help you! :)

Comment: div in which you are appending , can you control it using css. If yes then easy fix should be using overflow:scroll and height : fixed height property

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The solution I have provided works randomly. Will try your fix and update my reponse. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I this randomly solved it, by recalculating the size of the container and changing it:

$("#main-content").css({ height:$("#inner-content").height() });

I think the final solution is to do what qwfddq suggested, which is setting the overflow to auto before calling the html() function:

```js
function showParticipants(){
 
 if($('#action').val() != 0){
    $.ajax('participants.php', {
    beforeSend: function(){
   modal();
    },
    success: function(data) {
   $("#main-content").css({ overflow:"auto" });
                        $('#showParticipantsContainer').html(data);
   modal();
    },
    data: { ajax: 'showParticipants', idAction: $('#actions').val(), },
    error: showError
    }); 
 }else{
  $('#showParticipantsContainer').empty();
  $('#resultMessageDiv').empty();
 }
}
```